# semi-continuity of sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $i: Y\subset X$ is a closed subvariety of a variety $X$.

Suppose there is an exact sequence of coherent sheaves on $X$:
$$
0\rightarrow A \rightarrow B\rightarrow i_*C\rightarrow 0
$$

Suppose $C$ is locally free on $Y$.
Pulling the above exact sequence on $Y$, does it still remain left exact.
Iam bit confused whether $Tor^1(i_*C, O_Y)$  is zero or not.

Comment: Why is your second sequence exact (on the left)? Pull-back is a tensor operation and (hence) only right exact.

Comment: It does not, most of the time. Similarly the Tor is almost never zero.

Comment: I saw that to check $Tor^1=0$, it suffices to check at stalks.
In this case, if $p$ is a point on $X-Y$, then $i_*(O_Y)=0$, hence $Tor^1=0$.
If $p\in Y$ then since $C$ is assumed to be locally free, it is free at the stalk at p, hence $Tor^1$ is again zero.
Is this correct.

Comment: Yes, Tor will be zero away from $Y$, but it won't be zero on $Y$. It's important that you are taking $\mathrm{Tor}_X$ and not $\mathrm{Tor}_Y$.